# Limit the number of attempts in Android

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, limit

I developed an android app in which `SMS` can be sent from application to any mobile number ...I would like to limit this process for four numbers of times. What I have to do for that ... I am giving my code here...

```
package com.example.sms;

import java.util.StringTokenizer;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity

{

    Button btnSendSMS, btnCredit;
    EditText txtPhoneNo, txtMessage;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        btnSendSMS = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSendSMS2);
        txtPhoneNo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPhoneNo2);
        txtMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtMessage2);
        btnCredit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);




        btnSendSMS.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()

        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 

            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                String message = txtMessage.getText().toString();
                String phoneNo = txtPhoneNo.getText().toString();

                StringTokenizer st=new StringTokenizer(phoneNo,",");
                while (st.hasMoreElements())

                {

                    String tempMobileNumber = (String)st.nextElement();
                    if(tempMobileNumber.length()>0 && message.trim().length()>0) {
                        sendSMS(tempMobileNumber, message);

                    }


                    else 

                    {

                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
                                "Please enter both phone number and message.", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }



            }


       }
            });




        btnCredit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, credits.class );
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });

    }




        private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message)
        {
            String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
            String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";

            PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
                new Intent(SENT), 0);

            PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
                new Intent(DELIVERED), 0);

          //---when the SMS has been sent---
            registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                    switch (getResultCode())
                    {
                        case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS sent", 
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;
                        case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Generic failure", 
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;
                        case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No service", 
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;
                        case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Null PDU", 
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;
                        case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Radio off", 
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;
                    }
                }
            },new IntentFilter(SENT));

            //---when the SMS has been delivered---
            registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                    switch (getResultCode())
                    {
                        case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS delivered", 
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;
                        case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS not delivered", 
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;                        
                    }
                }
            }, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));        

            SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
            sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, sentPI, deliveredPI);       


        }     





}
```

Comment: which process do you want to limit?

Comment: I would like to know ... how to limit the working of app to 30 days ... or using the app for sending SMS for 4 times..l ike number of operations to be limited to 4 times ...

Comment: You can use `SharedPreferences` and store the number of times the message is sent, and before sending a message, check if the value in `SharedPreference` is less the the required number of sent `SMS`.

Answer (score 0):

As AnujMathur_07 told you can use SharedPreferences which are pretty easy to use, but there is a but, if the user goes to the application data and suppress them, he will be able to send 4 new message etc.

So maybe you can use database which is not so easily deleted or, easily you can create a text file where you write something when the user send the last message .

Comment: can you give me some links for example

Comment: Android site is really good : 
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html

or saving and reading the text file : 
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html